# Auto video in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

Anyone know how to add the auto playing video background in iOS?  I am guessing its actually images?  But the video lasts for 15 seconds so if its images then at 24fps minimum that is a lot of images.

I tried using the UIImageView swapping of images, but it seems like a hack way to do this.

See Uber's app and I think Airbnb has it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them images as you guessed, or play video using either `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AvPlayer`. Just add any as a subview to your view and make it play at `viewWillAppear`. I used `AvPlayer` as the app home screen background before and it worked perfectly.